# offset count(*) / N columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do some job in few machines.
Need divide rows into equal parts for each machine.
Query with all conditions performed long time.
Is it possible to do this without additional request count(*), in one query.
Some like this:

```
select * from some_table
where some_rows = some_values
offset (count(*) / count_machines) * (machine_number - 1)
limit count(*) / count_machines
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  It is unclear what you really want to do.  What does "Need divide rows for equal parts for each machine" mean?

Comment: count rows in table = 100, and have 4 machines. 1st machine must get 1-25 row, 2: 26-50, 3: 51-75, 4: 76-100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I sometime do to split data into blocks is a simple modulo on some id:

```
select * from some_table
where some_rows = some_values
and mod(id, BLOCKS) = BLOCK - 1;
```

Replace BLOCKS with the number of machines and BLOCK with a number n from 1 to BLOCKS to retrieve block n.

(You can even speed this up with a function index on the modulo expression provided the number of machines is static and you need this more often.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same number of rows for each machine, then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by machine order by machine) as seqnum
      from some_table t
      where . . .
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel.
Use hash function on value(s) of the record and then modulo by the number of machines in order to get the machine which will hold the record.
If you'll choose the value(s) well you'll get good distribution, good performance and you'll know where is each record located.